# Spring Boot MVC Include JSP file inside another JSP File

Tags: java, spring-mvc, spring-boot, jsp

I have Spring MVC with spring boot,also I use JSP file for the View.
I have already use the JSP and JSTL library

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.embed</groupId>
        <artifactId>tomcat-embed-jasper</artifactId>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
```

I have no problem with the JSP and JSTL syntax for example

```
<c:set var="heading" scope="page" value="${0}" />

 <c:forEach var="menuGroup" items="${menuGroups}">
   <c:if test="${menuGroup.headingId != heading}">
       <c:if test="${menuGroup.headingIsDisplayed == 1}">
            <li class="menu-title text-white">${menuGroup.headingTitle}</li>
    </c:if> 
    <c:set var="heading" scope="page" value="${menuGroup.headingId}" />

 </c:if>

    <li class="has_sub">
     <a href="index.html" class="waves-effect">
        <i class="ti-home"></i>
        <span> ${menuGroup.menuGroupTitle}</span>
        <span class="pull-right"><i class="mdi mdi-chevron-right"></i> 
   </span>
    </a>

    <ul class="list-unstyled">

        <c:forEach var="menu" items="${menuGroup.menus}">

            <li><a href="${menu.menuPath}">${menu.menuTitle}</a></li>
        </c:forEach>

    </ul>
  </li>


 </c:forEach>
```

But when I use the JSP Include tag

```
      <jsp:include page="sidemenu.jsp" flush="true"></jsp:include>
```

It's not working!, the content from the sidemenu JSP file is not included in the Page and also there is no error message at all.

Is there any page setting or configuration that I missed?
Or the  tag Cannot be used in Spring Boot MVC project ??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The above should work perfectly. the only issue may be with the sidemenu.jsp file location.

So try to use something like below by helping to find jsp page which you are going to include.

```
<jsp:include page="/WEB-INF/JSPs/header/navigation.jsp"></jsp:include>
```

OR

`<jsp:include page="../sidemenu.jsp"></jsp:include>` //if one upper directory

Also refer [include-jsps-file-from-another-folder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18846556/how-to-include-jsps-file-from-another-folder)

Answer (score 2):

First, you need to find the actual path of your `sidemenu.jsp`. 

Then you have to use this path when including it. Like this,

```
<jsp:include page="../views/jsp/sidemenu.jsp" flush="true"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use: `<%@ include file=/included-file.jsp" %>`

Comment: jsp:include is included at runtime, include file is included before page is generated.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23835653/is-it-possible-to-include-an-expression-tag-inside-a-page-directive-in-jsp/23836659

Comment: the issue from the question is the wrong path, and actually, both way of including works well, right?